# copy all files from one folder to a destination folder name with a pattern match

Tags: batch-file

I'm trying to work out how to create a batch file to copy files from a folder on a network share (such as D:\folders\folderA) to a local folder on my C: drive that matches a specific naming convention (such as C:\Users\john\folderddmmyy0600). In my case I only want to copy the files to a folder that matches something like folder1202210600 so is it possible to use a regex match to accomplish this?

For example, would something like this work?

```
copy "D:\folders\folderA" *.* "C:\Users\john\folder\d+"
```

My batch file writing is not good, but would appreciate if I can get some opinions on this.

Thank you

Comment: Batch files do not support any regex, the only built-in command utility which has some type of regular expression capability, _(not very good)_, is findstr.exe. To find out how to use that, open a Command Prompt window, type `findstr /?`, and press the `[ENTER]` key. _Before you do so, might I advise that you, fill a flask of coffee, and grab a set of stress balls!_ As you've already mentioned that you have limited experience of batch file writing, what you should do instead is take a look at PowerShell, which does have regex support, and learning simple tasks with it will future proof you.

Answer (score 0):

Will look into the PowerShell option [Compo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6738015/compo), thank you.